# Score test using restricted mle

Tags: lagrange-multipliers, reml

I am doing a study on Rao score test and still confused about the score vector. How am I supposed to calculate the score vector? Can I just use (ˆθn - θn) for the score vector? As I understood that score vector is the gradient right.